Issue with live preview & other live servers
The issue is that none of live server/preview is working when I try to check my website. It's only trying to load it but always fails & I can't keep working due that. To me it seems like internet problem but if I had internet issues I wouldn't be able to do other things which I can.


I've tried to re-install VSCode & extensions but it's not working, also tried to restart my routed multiple times but issue remains & I'm out of options.

Sorry for the format of the questions & if I made any English grammar mistakes.

Is there any JS? I once had a loop that basically broke my page and made it unable to load. I'd go though and comment out any loops temporarily to see if that fixes the problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
